# How to create a DataGenerator for Numpy Data

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, imagedatagenerator

as we know, in Keras it is possible to use many functions like ImageDataGenerator or dataset_from_image to generate a train/test data from directories.
In my situation, the data is organized in the following way:

```
/hog_features
         /train_data
              /class_a
                 a1.npy
                 a2.npy
                 ...
             /class_b
                 b1.npy
                 b2.npy
                 ...
             /class_c
                 c1.npy
                 c2.npy
                 ...
       /test_data
            /class_a
                a1.npy
                a2.npy
                ...
           /class_b
                b1.npy
                b2.npy
                ...
           /class_c
                c1.npy
                c2.npy
                ...
```

I would like to ask if someone can help me to know how to find an appropriate way to create a generator for the data in order to compile a CNN (Conv1D) model.
Notes: The .npy files are vectors (288,).

Comment: You can pass numpy arrays as input for CNN. Or you can use `ImageDataGenerator.flow()`.

Comment: @Djinn Yes, but what about labels? How can I get y_train?

Comment: You'll need to get the labels from the directory name. In your case, you'll need to do this before you call `flow()`. You can do a loop on `os.listdir(train_dir)` to create an array of labels. It looks like you're trying to mix the process of `flow()` and `flow_from_directory()`. That'd actually be an interested pull request. You could also convert the.npy files to their respective images and use `flow_from_directory()`. But getting the labels from the directory names might be easier for now.

Comment: a tutorial on how to do that is located at https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

Answer (score 0):

a non-elegant solution is to recreate the dataset with the files in jpg format. Code below can convert a jpg image to .npy (to_jpg=False) or npy to jpg (to_jpg=True).
Then use ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory as your generator. I will assume your dataset is in C:\hog_features. I set to name for the directory to hold the converted images to C:\jpg

```
import os
import numpy as np
import shutil
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm

def converter(train_path, test_path, destination_dir, to_jpg):
# if destination_dir exists, erase it and start with an expty directory
    if os.path.isdir(destination_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(destination_dir)
    os.mkdir(destination_dir)
    dataset_list = [train_path, test_path]
    names=['train_data', 'test_data']
    zipped_list=zip(names, dataset_list)
    for name, dataset in zipped_list:
        dest_dataset_path=os.path.join(destination_dir, name)
        os.mkdir(dest_dataset_path) # make train and test directories in destination directory
        classes=os.listdir(dataset)
        for klass in classes:
            class_path=os.path.join(dataset, klass)
            dest_class_path=os.path.join(dest_dataset_path, klass)
            os.mkdir(dest_class_path)
            flist=os.listdir(class_path)
            desc=f'{name:10s}-{klass:10s}'
            for f in tqdm(flist,ncols=110, unit='file', desc=desc, colour='blue'): # iterate through files in the class
                fpath=os.path.join(class_path,f)
                index=f.rfind('.') 
                fname=f[:index]
                if to_jpg:
                    # convert from npy to jpg
                    img=np.load(fpath) # assuming the .npy images are in rgb format
                    #img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) #convert to bgr image format
                    fname=fname + ".jpg"
                    dest_fpath=os.path.join(dest_class_path, fname)
                    img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                    cv2.imwrite(dest_fpath, img)
                else:
                    #convert from jpg to npy
                    img=cv2.imread(fpath)
                    img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #convert to rgb image format                    
                    dest_fpath=os.path.join(dest_class_path, fname)
                    np.save(dest_fpath, img)

train_path=r'C:\hog_featurestrain_data'
test_path = r'C:\hog_features\test_data'
destination_dir=r'C:\Temp\people\jpg'
to_jpg=True
converter(train_path, test_path, destination_dir, to_jpg)
```